# MYSQL - Select formatted date and also count the formatted date

Tags: mysql

Currently i am trying to select a formatted date and also count them from this column [here](http://prntscr.com/j1ajgf). When i execute this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT('connectedOn',"%H:00:00")) AS 'Time' FROM 'connection'
```

then i get all the dates formatted and once. Then when i add a count like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT('connectedOn',"%H:00:00")) AS 'Time', COUNT(*) AS 'TimeCounted' FROM 'connection' GROUP BY 'connectedOn'
```

then it gives me this result:

[image]

The count only counts the distinct values, but i want it to count all values. I know this type of distinct count works because im also using it elsewhere, but now i also have to change the date format.

I hope you guys and gals know a way for me to select a formatted date and the counted times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the formatted time, not the time in the table, so that all the times with the same hour will be grouped together in the count.

```
GROUP BY Time
```

Or, since the formatted time is the same as the hour of the table column, you can do:

```
GROUP BY HOUR(connectedOn)
```

BTW, there's no need to use `DISTINCT` when using `GROUP BY`. Grouping prevents duplicates. And the fact that you used `DISTINCT` as if it's a function suggests that you don't understand how it works. It's not a function that applies to a specific column, it's a keyword that applies to the entire `SELECT` list.

Comment: Thank you that helped alot i was trying all day!